# Bootstrap 4 custom variables doesn't override

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I have an main styles.scss like this:

```
 //@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Core variables and mixins
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "components/variables";
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/variables";
```

I try to override the success variable in my `components/variables` like this:

`$green:   #71c835 !important;`

But it keeps picking up the color of the bootstrap `variables.scss` which is 
`$green:   #28a745 !default;`

To create a clear view I allready tried to switch the sequence of these two files like this:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "components/variables";
```

It really drives me crazy  how can I simply override the bootstrap variables

Comment: Have you tried changing the loading sequence of the SCSS?
You can load a file containing overridden variables at last.

Comment: Whatt do you mean?

Comment: You're importing "components/variables" before the "components/bootstrap/scss/variables", so what I am suggesting is that you can change the sequence of importing these two files so that file with your variables will be imported at last.

Comment: allready tried to switch these two but doesn't work.

Comment: import "bootstrap-variables";
import "custom-variables";
import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
import "bootstrap-override";

I've done the same thing and it did work for me.

// removed @ due to mentions

Comment: Are you creating this file with node-sass?

Comment: Could you give us more information? Are you using node-sass or something else? Also are you sure your custom variable file including successfully?

Comment: Is your file structure setup correctly i.e the variables folder seems to be in a different file structure to the rest of your sass files - maybe it not looking in the correct folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$green:   #71c835 !important;` means *Set the value of the green variable to this hex code followed by important*.

It doesn't mean *Set the value of the green variable to this hex code and ignore subsequent attempts to change that value*.

---

You can't prevent a variable from being changed.

You have to write your code in the right order.

If you want to override `../components/bootstrap/scss/variables` from `components/variables` then import `components/variables` **after** the other one.

Comment: Do you maybe have an other idea of solving this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the first case and remove `!default`

```
.....
@import "components/variables";
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/variables";
```

Copy paste the variable you want to override and change the value. and remove the `!default` attribute. Compile it again.

The `!default` attribute works like reverse of !important. So it takes takes the value of previously declared variable. so remove the `!default`

`!important;` //always wins.

`!default;` //if the var already has been assigned take that one instead. -[Reference](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sass-default)

---

So now `components/variables`

```
 $green:   #71c835;
```

and `../components/bootstrap/scss/variables`

```
 $green:   #28a745;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I think this is the correct answer as of 2018.  I had to place the `@import` of my custom variables **above** the `@import` path to BS4 _variables.scss

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you create override.scss and put hem AFTER you're variables.scss

```
@import "../components/bootstrap/scss/variables.scss";
@import "custome/scss/override.scss";
```

Code override.scss :

```
 $green: #you_code;
```